# Synchronous AJAX request with JSONP

Tags: javascript, iphone, ajax, json, jsonp

My understanding is that Safari on iPhone will not play audio (html5) from an asynchronous thread. This is to limit the playing of audio such that it is only a response to user interactions, such as clicking on buttons. However, this presents a problem for me. I wish to play a sound as a result of a button click, but having clicked the button, I need to establish the address of the mp3 file which is to be played and I am currently doing this via an asynchronous AJAX call, as follows:

```
function play() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://apifree.forvo.com/etc/etc', jsonpCallback: "pronounce", jsonp: false, cache: true,           dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (json) {
            if (json.items.length !== 0) {
                _player.src = json.items[0].mp3path;
                _player.load();
            }
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see I am calling _player.load() (and subsequently _player.play()) in the callback and this will not work on iphone, but will work on my pc. How  can I make this AJAX call synchronous or how might I solve this problem?

Here are two fiddles to demonstrate the problem:

Asyncronous _player.load() not working on iPhone but working on PC: http://jsfiddle.net/8muHa/27/

Syncronous _player.load() working on both iPhone and PC: http://jsfiddle.net/8muHa/28/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must load the name of the file asynchronously, can you prefetch it?  If there aren't too many of these it should be fine to just prefetch the values (say when the user navigates to this section of your site) and then call `_player.play()` when they click the button.